# Can HTML5 Video be transmitted directly to the same TCP server that's serving HTTP?

Tags: javascript, html, video, tcp, stream

It seems that it is quite simple now to use HTML5 to display content from a video camera, assuming you are using the latest Chrome or the Beta of Firefox. [Viewer Demo](http://www.simpl.info/getusermedia/)

It is also clear that using HTML5 only (JavaScript, and no plugins), you can run a videoconference. [Video-conference Demo](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) (requires latest Chrome or Firefox Nightly) The preferred way to transfer video appears to be a direct peer to peer transmission, and that is how the example works. [Additional Reading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

However, **my preference** is for the video to be transmitted to the server, as a one-way video feed, and for the server to decide on its own what to do with the video stream. (save, broadcast, transform, etc)

Can you suggest a way for me to hard-code a destination port number and IP address for the data? Is there a way to do this with TCP? Is there a way for me to perform my own handshake before the stream is applied to the TCP connection? Can the TCP connection be encrypted with TLS?

**Possible clue:** The [Video-conference Demo](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) writes to the JavaScript `console` log, and viewing that log indicates that it supports a small variety of peer to peer protocols. a) Peer to peer data can be transmitted on the same subnet or through the internet, or if the Firewall does not permit, then through an echo server (I think that is an option on some implementations). b) Data can be transmitted on either TCP or UDP.

I have also read that [RTCDataChannel](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel) supports DTLS. (so maybe it also supports plain TLS) Either way, I feel that it could be coerced into making a direct connection to the server, by the server pretending to be a video-conference peer, but I don't know how.

I am hoping to use this solution because the demos performed much better (more FPS, less latency, even before the network layer) than the Java-based alternatives I have found. It is possible I could use Flash instead, but I am not familiar with it, and I feel that using HTML5 will be better for the future, even if at present it is slightly less appealing. (requires Chrome, or an experimental version of Firefox)

Comment: Javascript can't do pure TCP connections, but WebSockets are very close to it. They also can be TLS-encrypted.

Comment: I would probably accept an answer that describes how take the media stream and apply it to a WebSocket. My plain TLS server doubles as an HTTPS server, and can also double as a WebSockets server just fine.

Comment: Sorry, but I only have experience with web sockets, but none with getting video streams from webcams in web applications. When I would know anything about that, I would have written an answer.